# How to set up a new user with admin rights on a USB Ubuntu 12.04 installation?

Tags: 12.04, usb, password, usb-drive

I have successfully installed 12.04 LTS on a USB stick with persistence and it is working well.  I have even managed to add Flash player and get wifi working.

I would like to password protect the USB stick. However, when I try this with administrator privileges and I try to login again it does not recognise the password. The password/user name combination DOES work for a standard user though!  Quite annoying.

Any ideas on a solution anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting yourself up as a new user with password in users and groups?
This worked for me.

Having a password with a persistent install is not much use though, as it is easy to mount the casper-rw persistence file and get at all the data.

Better to do a Full install to USB if you want security.

Comment: That is an excellant point which I had not considered!  I shall attempt to do a full USB pendrive install and see how I get on.  Many thanks for your time.